# Multiple commands on one line with Command Prompt and ADB

Tags: c#, android, .net, adb, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to get an automated Android S-OFF method going in my program, but I can't seem to get two commands to follow each other in the same window. For example, my code right now is:

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/k adb shell chmod 744 /data/local/tmp/soffbin3");
process.WaitForExit();
```

However, when I run that, nothing occurs in the window. I tried to have the second command follow the first one like this:

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/k adb shell & chmod 744 /data/local/tmp/soffbin3");
process.WaitForExit();
```

However, the inclusion of `&` makes it so the second command doesn't go until the first command completes, and because `"adb shell"` isn't really a command that completes, it doesn't do the second command.

It was also suggested to me that I replace the `/k` with a `/c`, which may as well work, but the window closes almost instantly after opening that command, and I can't confirm that anything actually happened.

I've tried a few variations to try and get it to work, but nothing has worked so far. Is the answer something simple that I'm missing? I really hope it is.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This command work for me

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", @"/k adb pull data/data/com.sales.recorder/databases/SalesRecorder c:\adb");
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Please format code as code. Explain how you modified the string to make it work, its not very obvious

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the Verbatim escape for the command to avoid issues with your Literal commands.
The @ is a verbatim escape so that the information following it in Double Quotes is run as a literal command.

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", @"/k adb shell & chmod 744 /data/local/tmp/soffbin3");
    process.WaitForExit();
```